# Add configurable Product to Wishlist (not simple product option within the product)

Tags: configurable-product, wishlist

Is there an option to add a configurable product to the wishlist without the user having to select an option (like just add the shirt without specifying a size or color)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be available out of the box.
Create an account on the magento demo website and try to add this to the wishlist: http://demo.magentocommerce.com/plaid-cotton-shirt-589.html.

If it does not work on your instance, maybe there is something wrong with your theme.

Comment: If the options are required, it does not work since when clicking on "add to wishlist" Magento validates the form and checks for the required fields ...

Comment: Did you try the link I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Sorry, you are right of course. The template added a `onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;"` to the wishlistsubmit URL which caused the validation.